# Can't boot windows. Is cloning the HD and restoring after a Windows 7 reinstall a good solution

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

Can't get past the black screen with cursor in Windows 7 when I start my laptop. I've tried many solutions but I think it's not fixable.

If I clone this drive and then reinstall windows, will I be able to restore the HD using the clone without causing it to have the same problems?

I can access all my files in Ubuntu, but Windows won't start no matter what.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If I clone this drive and then reinstall windows, will I be able to restore the HD using the clone without causing it to have the same problems?

If you clone a drive, all you're doing is making an exact copy of the drive. Every single bit of data that was on the previous version will be on the next drive.

So No, that won't work and WILL cause the same problem.

It's great you can access your files through linux, so my suggestion is to back up your data on there and re-install windows with a fresh copy then move your data back.